# How to add configure event for zip file in AWS

Tags: python, aws-lambda

How to add `configure event` if we are uploading as zip

[image]

Normally configure event is available as like below
[image: zip]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could invoke your lambda with configure event from AWS console no matter if it is archive or inline-edit.

See the dropdown before `Test` button, once you have created your event just run the button as usual.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

why would you need to configure test events when uploading a lambda? Those are just meant for trigger the lambda for testing. If you want to add events to the lambda on deployment like so:

```
functions:
  createUser: # Function name
    handler: handler.createUser # Reference to file handler.js & exported function 'createUser'
    events: # All events associated with this function
      - http:
          path: users/create
          method: post
```

I would take a look at serverless, makes it very simple to deploy resources to AWS.

[Serverless](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/intro/)